# How to change the A3C Tensorflow example to play Atari games?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I followed the [Tensorflow tutorial](https://medium.com/tensorflow/deep-reinforcement-learning-playing-cartpole-through-asynchronous-advantage-actor-critic-a3c-7eab2eea5296) which implemented A3C in order to do well in the cartpole environment, and wanted to use it as a starting point for a game-playing bot for some Atari games. However, if I simply change the environment to, say, Frostbite-v0, I get this error when the worker threads start:

```
Exception in thread Thread-4:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "a3c.py", line 286, in run
    action = np.random.choice(self.action_size, p=probs.numpy()[0])
  File "mtrand.pyx", line 1135, in mtrand.RandomState.choice
ValueError: object too deep for desired array
```

I'm a complete noob in Deep Learning, but I guess the problem is in how the network just has `Dense` Layers taking the input which in this case, taking [this](https://github.com/openai/gym/wiki/Table-of-environments) as a reference, has an environment with a different shape, meaning not `Box(4,)` as in the cartpole example but `Box(210, 160, 3)`.

How do I change the example so that it works properly with such an observation? Do I have to add/change layers? And in general so that it performs correctly for the Frostbite-v0 environment?

Edit: Another thing that bugs me is that the `state_size` parameter in the `ActorCriticModel` is set but never used, at least from an outside perspective. Does the model use it in any way or does it just sit there as an unused parameter?

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid you are going to need to change lots of things: first, to deal with inputs that are images you would need to add convolutional layers. Second, traditionally images of atari games are downsampled from 210x160x3 to 64x64(tiny grayscale images)or something like that. So if you are a beginner I think it might be better to check out some other tutorials. For example [famous blog post from a famous guy Karpathy](http://karpathy.github.io/2016/05/31/rl/)